# Missing required extension: XMLRPC

Tags: php, zend-framework, xml-rpc, zend-xmlrpc

I'm trying to install KnowledgeTree Community Edition on my CentOS VPS. One of the requirements for this was ZendServer - Which I had to install via their universal installer as installing via YUM was just straight out failing. I assume due to CPanel...

Anyway, I got ZendServer installed and then downloaded the source of KnowledgeTree and dumped it in my webroot. When trying to run the web installer, however, I get:

```
Missing required extension: XMLRPC
```

ZendServer reports XMLRPC is turned on. I've downloaded, via YUM, `xmlrpc` and `php-xmlrpc`. I can't get this error to go away.

I don't think it's necessarily got anything to do with KnowledgeTree. According to Google, I'm the only person having this issue. So how can I get XMLRPC working on PHP? Despite the fact ZendServer already thinks it is working...

Answer (score 0):

Freshly-installed PHP extension packages won't be recognized by the process running PHP (usually a web server) until it is restarted/bounced/whatnot.

Comment: I just stopped ZendServer, restarted Apache via CPanel and then started ZendServer again. It's still reporting 'Missing required extension: XMLRPC'

Comment: Did you install CPanel's php-xmlrpc package? Do `phpinfo()` or `php -m` list the xmlrpc module?

Comment: Nah, it's not showing 'xmlrpc'. I installed php-xmlrpc via SSH. Should I remove that (via YUM) and install it via CPanel?

Comment: I don't know all of CPanel's internals. you can run `rpm -qa '*php*'` to list all installed PHP packages, and then extrapolate the relevant package name to install from that.

Comment: CPanel is reporting XMLRPC and I just installed XMLRPC2 (via CPanel) but `php -m` isn't showing XMLRPC :/

Comment: The `php` executable may be using different modules from the php running in the web server. Trust the web server if it's what you need.

Comment: But XMLRPC isn't being reported as a loaded module in the output of phpinfo(). It only shows `xmlrpc_error_number` and `xmlrpc_errorserrors` under Core Configuration. The only place where XMLRPC is reported to be working is ZendServer. KnowledgeTree is still reporting it's missing >.<

Comment: ... Okay, I admit that I'm stumped then. Perhaps your web server isn't using CPanel's PHP after all...

Comment: Any ideas on what I can do to check/solve this? Can I check for multiple instances of PHP? Getting XMLRPC installed is proving to be a PITA

Comment: Unfortunately nothing in `phpinfo()` indicates which one is being used. You could try sifting through `rpm -qa '*php*'`, but removing the wrong one may break CPanel.

Comment: The only output I receive from `rpm -qa '*php*'` is `php-common-5.1.6-24.el5_4.5`, `php-xmlrpc-5.1.6-24.el5_4.5` o.0

Comment: I'm thinking I'll need to recompile PHP to include '--with-xmlrpc' or whatever the flag is... But how do I go about doing this? Will it break CPanel/Webhost Manager?